# In App Purchase product always return true in Windows Mobile 10

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-10

I have an app currently developed for Windows Phone 8.1 RT and it works fine in WM 10 as well. But IAPs are always returning true. So, in WM10, user has no option to buy. It's the full version by default.

```
licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
_isFull = licenseInformation.ProductLicenses[inappKey].IsActive;
```

The above code always returns true in WM10. It works fine in WP 8.1 RT. What could be the issue?

Comment: Once fulfillment is received by store its Active!

Comment: What fulfillment? it's always active without anything.

Comment: Please describe product..

Comment: It's a Durable In-App Purchase product. This is the method I've used. It was working all good in WP 8.1 but not in WM 10.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-in-app-product-purchases?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396